# retrieve resultset based on where clause condition order in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, where-clause

Consider the following table

```
ColID  Value
  A     100
  B     200
  C     300
  D     400
  E     500
```

What is the query for retrieving the values for colID 'C','A','D' in the same order?

Comment: What is the "same order"? You mean alphabetically?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That makes those `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` orgies totally unnecessary.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that particular ordering you would have to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColID IN ('C', 'A', 'D') 
   ORDER BY 
      CASE ColID 
         WHEN 'C' THEN 0 
         WHEN 'A' THEN 1 
         ELSE 2 
      END
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)?

```sql
SELECT [Value]
FROM testTable
WHERE colID IN ('C','A','D')
ORDER BY (CASE colID WHEN 'C' THEN 1 WHEN 'A' THEN 2 WHEN 'D' THEN 3 END);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from Tablex Where ColId in ('C', 'A', 'D') order by ColId  -- This will yield 'A', 'C', 'D' order
```

If you needed it to return in 'C' 'A' 'D' order, you would need to have another column like:

```
ColID Value  Ordinal
A        100    2
B        200    5
C        300    1
D        400    3
E        500    4
```

Then do:

```
Select * from Tablex Where ColId in ('C', 'A', 'D') order by Ordinal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`select *
from your table
Where ColId in ('C', 'A', 'D')`

As for that particular order, you can't sort by either ColId or Value. An order by will not give it to you in that order.